# How can I override filter:blur and box-shadow from parent div on a contained div?

Tags: css, reset

I have a main div which has a background image with `filter:blur` and a `box-shadow` overlay.

How can I override filter:blur and box-shadow from parent div on a  contained div?

The following is my attempt:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        #home_main {
            margin: -30px;
            background-size: cover;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url('img/bg.jpg') !important;
            filter: blur(2px);
            overflow: hidden;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }

        #home_content {
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff !important;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: fixed;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-shadow: none;
            font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;

            filter: initial !important;
            box-shadow: initial !important;
        }

            #home_content h1 {
                font-size: 42px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    </style>
<div id="home_main">
  <div id="home_content">
    Info Management System
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a wrapper around both divs. Your'e already using positioning.

```css
.wrap { position: relative; }

#home_main {
    margin: -30px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    filter: blur(2px);
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(200,0,0,.3);

  /* added so the div shows here */
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
    background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/130763/pexels-photo-130763.jpeg');
}

#home_content {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff ;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 240px; /* width of image div minus it's negative margins */
}

#home_content h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="home_content">
       Info Management System
    </div>
  
    <div id="home_main"></div>
</div>
```

This will allow you to apply the filter and box shadow to only one of the divs. But as a direct child, you can't remove the parent's filter or box shadow. Much like opacity, some properties affect the parent and all its' children.

Comment: Let me see if i get this... The background div is no longer a container?

Comment: It's a container, but it is just holding that background image. When you apply a filter to a container, everything inside that container will also be affected by the filter... you can't selectively choose which child elements are *not* affected by the filter. Just stack containers via positioning so they *look* like they are contained within each other.